# PHP redirecting after incorrect login

Tags: php

So this script is from a tutorial I read so in honesty I don't understand every part of it as I'm new to PHP and this isn't all my code! (some is and some isn't)

So basically it's a login script, after login it redirects the user to an account page which is great. However if they enter the wrong login details it still redirects them to that page. This is obviously bad as it displays the users account page minus all the bits that are populated through a database connection to their details as this hasn't been established.

Here's my code that the HTML form submits to (I've copied the whole file but I believe the main code is at the bottom from "//store login status into the session" but I could be wrong of course:

```
<?php
include 'user.php';
include 'index.php';
$user = new User();
if(isset($_POST['signupSubmit'])){
    //check whether user details are empty
    if(!empty($_POST['first_name']) && !empty($_POST['last_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['confirm_password'])){
        //password and confirm password comparison
        if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['confirm_password']){
            $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Confirm password must match with the password.'; 
        }else{
            //check whether user exists in the database
            $prevCon['where'] = array('email'=>$_POST['email']);
            $prevCon['return_type'] = 'count';
            $prevUser = $user->getRows($prevCon);
            if($prevUser > 0){
                $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
                $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Email already exists, please use another email.';
            }else{
                //insert user data in the database
                $userData = array(
                    'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
                    'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
                    'email' => $_POST['email'],
                    'password' => md5($_POST['password']),
                    'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
                    'postcode' => $_POST['postcode'],
                    'travel' => $_POST['travel'],
                    'driver' => $_POST['driver'],
                    'main' => $_POST['main'],
                    'prop' => $_POST['prop'],
                    'hooker' => $_POST['hooker'],
                    'second_row' => $_POST['second_row'],
                    'flanker' => $_POST['flanker'],
                    'eight' => $_POST['eight'],
                    'scrum_half' => $_POST['scrum_half'],
                    'fly_half' => $_POST['fly_half'],
                    'centre' => $_POST['centre'],
                    'winger' => $_POST['winger'],
                    'full_back' => $_POST['full_back'],
                    'available' => $_POST['available'],

                );
                $insert = $user->insert($userData);
                //set status based on data insert
                if($insert){
                    $sessData['status']['type'] = 'success';
                    $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'You have registered successfully, log in with your credentials.';
                }else{
                    $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
                    $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
        $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'All fields are mandatory, please fill all the fields.'; 
    }
    //store signup status into the session
    $_SESSION['sessData'] = $sessData;
    $redirectURL = ($sessData['status']['type'] == 'success')?'index.php':'registration.php';
    //redirect to the home/registration page
    header("Location:".$redirectURL);
}elseif(isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])){
    //check whether login details are empty
    if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
         //get user data from user class
        $conditions['where'] = array(
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'password' => md5($_POST['password']),
            'status' => '1'
        );
        $conditions['return_type'] = 'single';
        $userData = $user->getRows($conditions);
        //set user data and status based on login credentials
        if($userData){
            $sessData['userLoggedIn'] = TRUE;
            $sessData['userID'] = $userData['id'];
            $sessData['status']['type'] = 'success';
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Welcome '.$userData['first_name'].'!';
        }else{
            $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try again.';
        }
    }else{
        $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
        $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Enter email and password.'; 
    }
    //store login status into the session
    $_SESSION['sessData'] = $sessData;
    //redirect to the home page
    header("Location:http://www.example.com/successful_login.php");
}elseif(!empty($_REQUEST['logoutSubmit'])){
    //remove session data
    unset($_SESSION['sessData']);
    session_destroy();
    //store logout status into the ession
    $sessData['status']['type'] = 'success';
    $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'You have logout successfully from your account.';
    $_SESSION['sessData'] = $sessData;
    //redirect to the home page
    header("Location:http://www.example.com");
}else{
    //redirect to the home page
    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```

I've tried changing:

```
 $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try again.';
```

To:

```
 $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try again.';
    header("Location:www.loginpage.com");
```

But it makes no difference at all

Comment: always use `exit();` after redirect

Comment: Don't use `md5` make use of `password_hash` instead and *always* validate *all* incoming user input to ensure it is what it claims to be.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, I've asked a friend to help me with the encryption as I don't want to get that wrong. I will add in exit(); thank you I had seen that elsewhere but was scared to break anything as what I had worked! Out of interest do you know why this is getting downvoted? My last question did as well but I am honestly trying to solve this myself and show what I've done to try and solve it.

Comment: In security, don't mix up *encryption* and *hashing*, you want to hash (non reversible) not encrypt (reversible).

Comment: To be a bit picky, you don't "encrypt" passwords, you "hash" them.

Comment: Haha fair enough and point noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `header("Location:http://www.example.com/successful_login.php");` To just underneath: `if($userData){` So that it looks like this:

```
if($userData){
    $sessData['userLoggedIn'] = TRUE;
    $sessData['userID'] = $userData['id'];
    $sessData['status']['type'] = 'success';
    $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Welcome '.$userData['first_name'].'!';
    header("Location:http://www.example.com/successful_login.php");
}
```

The reason why you are always getting redirected to the homepage is because the redirect code needs to be within some logic which basically says (pseudo code):

```
if(user is logged in){
    redirectToHomePage;
} else {
    showMessage('Incorrect password');
}
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly thank you Lewis, also appreciate the extra info as to why it works. Really helps out us newbies!

Comment: Ah just noticed one thing though, when the wrong password is entered it now stays on useraccount.php rather than returning to the original page with the error message. I tried adding in the header(Location:""); info where it was before but this hasn't worked.

Comment: No problem buddy, let me know if you need any more help! :)